# VMWare and Linux Mint 18 window resolution

Tags: linux-mint, vmware

**EDIT:**
I just figured it out on my own. In VMWare you should put the video card settings to Auto-detect settings. Now there is no freezing anymore when setting a new resolution.

I saw many questions here facing this issue and I tried as much as I can do with my limited knowledge about Linux to solve this issue for me, but nothing worked so far.

I've installed the latest Linux Mint (Sarah; 18) on an VMWare server. Everything went fine, I can use it. The only problem is - as I pointed out in the title - that the resolution of Mint isn't automatically adjusting to the window of the VMWare itself.

I'm using the vSphere Client to access my Linux VM. I can click on `View > Fit Guest Now` to let VMWare do the job, but nothing but a small shake is happening to the window.

When I try to set the resolution under the Display option of Mint itself, the VM just freezes and I have to restart the VM.

[I used](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/297811/problem-with-mint-18-and-vmware-tools) `sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools open-vm-tools-desktop` to get the package that's doing the job actually.

I'm not sure if I've set up the VM properly. Maybe there are some small but important options I configured incorrect?

And I did updated as much as possible to have all latest libraries and stuff.

Because of this problem I cannot access the OK button on the Update Manager window.

Comment: I just figured it out on my own. In VMWare you should put the video card settings to `Auto-detect settings`. Now there is no freezing anymore when setting a new resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fred, you should set this as the answer.. I almost missed it when trying to solve this problem in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

install the tools as mentioned in the question.. then shutdown and edit the VM's video card settings

[image]

Comment: Sure, sorry, been a long time since I asked the question and was working with Linux.